# Mean & Variance after applying a Maximum function n-times

Tags: normal-distribution, extreme-value

I am trying to solve a statistics problem with very little statistics theory.  I can determine a solution to my problem by writing a simulation program, but I really need to have the proper formula instead.

I have a Gaussian Normal distribution with Mean x and Variance v.  I have defined a second function that is simply the Maximum value of this Normal Distribution, after n samples.  I need to know the x' and v' of this Maximum function, as they relate to the original Normal distribution's x and v variables.

An example where this may be used is in calculating the likelihood of failure of a redundant system.  For example, if the likelihood of failure for a single component can be characterized by a Normal distribution of f(x,v), and n such components are used in a redundant system such that all must fail for the system to completely fail, then what is likelihood of failure Mean and Variance of the redundant system?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=max+normal+distribution).  The threads on the distribution of the maximum of IID normals indicate you would have to find these moments through some form of numerical integration.  For sufficiently large $n$, asymptotic or approximate answers might be appealing.

Comment: Take Bill Huber's advice. Problems in reliability and many other areas of study involve the maximum and minimum and there approximate distributions.  Google "Extreme value theory" and you will find an overwhelming amount of literature.